# LINQ to SQL partial class OnValidate Changeaction.Delete

Tags: asp.net, .net, validation, linq-to-sql

I have a LINQ partial class:

```
public partial class resp
{
    public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(respName))
            yield return new RuleViolation("Responsibility name required", "respName");
        yield break;
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        // Quick method for checking to see whether an object contains any RuleViolations
        get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
    }

    partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
    {
        // Hook to LINQ to be notified before db is actually persisted .. and check to make sure resp is not used by respApprover or approvals
        if (action == ChangeAction.Delete && ((respApprovers.Count() != 0 || approvals.Count() != 0)))
            throw new ApplicationException("You cannot delete a responsibility that is in use");
        if (!IsValid)
            throw new ApplicationException("Rule violations prevent saving");
    }
}
```

In my code I would like to be able to check whether a responsibility (dbo.resp) exists before it is deleted.

I am accomplishing this check with a hook to `OnValidate` as above `... if (action == ChangeAction.Delete)  ...` and returning an application exception if it fails.

Also, during normal validation, I would like to check to make sure rule violations aren't made (resp.respName in this case...)

So, normally I can just do a `try { } catch { var errors = resps.GetRuleViolations() }` and check whether I have validation errors.  Of course, that doesn't know what action is being taken (Changeaction.Delete)

I guess my main question is, how can I have `OnValidate` return a reason rather than crash my whole app when the `Changeaction` is delete.  Normally I would catch `GetRuleViolations` but if I put the 'if statement' in the `GetRuleViolations` ... it will always be true even during checks to see if the data was correct (in other words, `respApprovers.Count()` will matter even for checks on new insertions which I don't want to. I only want those count checks to be made on deletion)

Or possibly more simply stated: I want `GetRuleViolations` to tell me when someone attempts to delete resp that has `respApprovers.Count() > 0` or `approvals.Count() > 0` but only when the `OnValidate` `Changeaction` is delete.

Comment: This looks like LINQ to SQL, if correct please title and tag as such (otherwise may get answers for other LINQ providers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change GetRuleViolations to accept the ChangeAction parameter and add a parameterless version that calls it with ChangeAction.None (or Update or Insert, as appropriate).  Then move your check in there as you want.

```
public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations( ChangeAction action )
{
    if (action == ChangeAction.Delete) {
       ...
    }
    else {
       ...
    }
}

public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations()
{
    return GetRuleViolations( ChangeAction.None );
}
```